# spark graphx -creating list of graphs objects in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

I want to make the edges in the graph to be subgraphs. Then I want to join these subgraphs based on a criterion and form cliques. Basically I want to know how to create a list of `Graph` objects.

How can I achieve this using the Graph X API of Apache Spark in Scala?

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val cliques = ArrayBuffer[Graph[(String, Int),Int]]()

var edges = sc.textFile("edges.g3").map { 
  line => var fields = line.split("\\s+")

  println(line)

  val vertexArray = Array(
  (fields(0).toLong, (fields(0), 1)),
  (fields(1).toLong, (fields(1), 1)))

  val edgeArray = Array(
  Edge(fields(0).toLong,fields(1).toLong,0)
  )

  val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
  val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)

  val graph: Graph[(String, Int),Int] = new Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)

  cliques += graph

}
```

This code gives the error that class `Graph` is abstract, hence cannot be instantiated. Is there any way to create a list of graphs?

How to instantiate the Graph object is my main question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `new Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)` you need to use `Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)`. Check out some of the examples in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#example-property-graph).

Comment: i did that but somehow this is not working. initially i am creating a list  of graphs which contain only one edge .but what this your  code does is that it make reference to the same graph and all the graphs contains all the edges.I guess all the items of the listit is referencing the same graph

Comment: Your code listing has `new Graph` instead of `Graph`, and you mention it gives you the error message that `Graph` is abstract. Hence my answer. If you have other questions, feel free to ask them!

Comment: thanks.but thats not what i am looking ,sorry for misframing the question